# InDesign Paragraph Return Character from CSV file?

Tags: csv, import, merge, adobe, adobe-indesign

I am currently using the Data Merge functions of ID CS4 to import some data I have exported from a MySQL database. Although I can set ID to remove blank lines, this doesn't always work for my purpose because later lines contain data. As a result, there still appears whitespace in the outputted data.

Since I am using PHP to produce the CSV file, my question is this: is it possible for me to indicate an InDesign Paragraph Return character within the CSV file, so that the data can then in turn be imported and displayed as I wish.

For example, I have the tried the following examples, but nothing seems to work:

```
"code","description"
"12345", "Hardware\nTools"

"code","description"
"12345","Hardware \Z  Tools"
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this PDF](http://www.mayart.de/download/Indesign-IDML/special-idml-chars.pdf), in IDML you can specify a "forced line break" by using `&#x2028`, or you can force a "Paragraph break" by using `<br/>`.

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but you may be able to give it a try.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

Not sure why the first answer was accepted, as it is wrong.

Google still brings this thread in third position for "data merge indesign line break", so I thought I had to give a real anwser.

There is no magical character you can put in your CSV file to automatically generate line breaks in InDesign.

The [Adobe Help for InDesign](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-6c3ca.html) specifies :

> You cannot insert a line break within a field in the data source file. If it’s necessary to split a field across different lines, create two different fields, such as `<<Address1>>` and `<<Address2>>`.

If your number of lines is variable or if you don't want to create extra columns just for some line breaks, there is only one solution :

- Replace, in your CSV file, the line breaks by some specific character (`¤` for example) that would act as a line separator.
- Then, **after** the merge in InDesign, use the Find/Replace tool in the Edit Menu, in order to find your "line separator" and replace it back to a line break, that InDesign will understand.

I hope this will *really* help those who struggled like me with these line breaks in InDesign.